# does join() method in multi-threading affects concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading

When `thread.join()` method is used in a multi threaded environment, other threads have to wait until the current thread finishes it's execution.

Can someone please explain, how it affects the performance of multi-threading?
I mean, whether the performance is really reduced by this `join()` condition or not?

```
public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{

    Runnable run = () -> System.out.println("Inside run");
    Thread t[] = new Thread[5];
    int i=0;
    while(i<5){
        t[i]= new Thread(run);
        t[i].start();
        t[i].join();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "whether the performance is really reduced by this join() condition or not?" Use of join has little to do with performance, but rather correctness. If you need to wait for a thread to complete before doing the next thing in order for that thing to be correct, you use join.

Comment: In this specific example, there is little point in using multiple threads, since you wait for the started thread to complete. You may as well just run it in a single thread, by running the runnable directly.

Comment: `join` is not really a useful method in any case, since it requires a Thread to finish, and creating, starting and finishing threads is as a whole a very expensive operation. That's why java has thread-pools (Executor/ExecutorService implementations). It's much better to use `wait`/`notify` or the higher-level java.util.concurrent classes to synchronise threads.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Yes, it is better to use a thread pool instead of continually creating and destroying new threads. But, programs also sometimes need dedicated, long-running threads (e.g., a thread that monitors some source of events.) Thread pools don't solve every problem, and `t.join()` has its uses.

Comment: @Arun, It _never_ makes any sense to write `t.join()` immediately after `t.start()`. The entire point of threads is to allow two or more threads to make progress independently of each other. But, a thread that calls `t.start(); t.join();` makes no progress at all during the lifetime of the new thread that it started.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thread.join is actually implemented using `wait` and `notify`. It's a convenience method over doing the `wait` and the `notify` yourself. But the OP is talking about the performance of `Thread.join` and for long-running threads like you describe, the performance of `Thread.join` is a non-issue.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, That's all good, but it still never makes sense for thread A to create thread B and then join thread B without doing anything else in between. You can always improve that by simply having thread A do whatever thread B was going to do at that point.

Answer (score 1):

It does affect performance, but only for one thread, that is actually calling it.

The problem of your example is that you call join in the loop.
So the main thread(one that is running the loop) will not start 2nd thread before first finishes.

Consider following example.

```
Runnable run = () -> {
        //Some computation here, but NO "performance penalty"
        System.out.println("Inside run");
    };
    Thread t[] = new Thread[5];
    int i=0;
    while(i<5){
        t[i]= new Thread(run);
        t[i].start();

        i++;
    }

    while(i<5){
        t[i].join();
    }
    //Some follow-up computation here, but WITH "performance penalty"
```